# issues with 1 pixel in Graphics2D and java.awt.geom.Area

Tags: java, pixel, graphics2d

I have 2 arrays of coordinates, basing on which i construct a polygon. Later if I draw this polygon, i get drawing 5x5 pixels (as it should be). BUT when i construct java.awt.geom.Area using the polygon as an argument, resulting area is 4x4 pixels. For some reason height and width of resulting area are 1 pixel smaller

Why does it happen? How to fix this? And I can't just add 1 pixel to some of polygon vertices' coordinates. Once more, what do i need is to create from an existing Polygon an Area object that INCLUDES ALL vertices of the polygon

```
int[] xpoints={50,54,54,50};
int[] ypoints={50,50,54,54};
int npoints=4;
Polygon p=new Polygon(xpoints,ypoints,npoints);
visible= new Area(p);
blackArea.subtract(visible);
```

Moreover, if i am not mistaking, if i create and draw a Rectangle2D.Float 5x5 then it will take 6x6 area. I am clearly missing something. Thank you sooo much for any help

Answer (score 1):

You mentioned that you *draw* the polygon. In this case, you have to take into account that you are drawing with the line just between (!) the pixels. And if the line has a width of 1.0 (with the default stroke), this will cause 5x5 pixels to be touched. In contrast to that, when you really *fill* the polygon, then it should really occupy only 4x4 pixels.

In any case, the result computed by the `Area` should be in line with the [definition of "insideness" in the Shape class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Shape.html#def_insideness).

The following image shows the "pixels" enlarged: The red pixels in the center are the pixels that are contained in a rectangular polygon (position (2,2), size (4,4)). The blue pixels are the pixels that are contained in the `Area` from which the polygon was subtracted. IF there were any pixels contained in both shapes, then these would be painted in magenta.

The green, semi-transparent "overlay" shows what *drawing* the polygon actually would produce (if the display was capable to show this): The lines are at the border between the pixels, but with a width of 1.0.

[image]

The code:

```
import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.Polygon;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;
import java.awt.geom.Area;
import java.awt.geom.Point2D;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class ContainsTest
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI()
    {
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.getContentPane().add(new ContainsTestPanel());
        f.setSize(500, 500);
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

}

class ContainsTestPanel extends JPanel
{
    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics gr)
    {
        super.paintComponent(gr);
        Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D)gr;
        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g.fillRect(0,0,getWidth(), getHeight());

        int[] xpoints={2,6,6,2};
        int[] ypoints={2,2,6,6};
        int npoints=4;
        Polygon p=new Polygon(xpoints,ypoints,npoints);
        Area visible = new Area(p);
        Area blackArea = new Area(new Rectangle(0,0,8,8));
        blackArea.subtract(visible);

        int size = 50;
        for (int x=0; x<8; x++)
        {
            for (int y=0; y<8; y++)
            {
                Point2D point = new Point(x,y);
                boolean inPoly = p.contains(point);
                boolean inArea = blackArea.contains(point);
                System.out.println(x+" "+y+" inPoly: "+inPoly+" inArea "+inArea);

                if (!inPoly && !inArea)
                {
                    g.setColor(Color.GRAY);
                }
                if (inPoly && !inArea)
                {
                    g.setColor(Color.RED);
                }
                if (!inPoly && inArea)
                {
                    g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
                }
                if (inPoly && inArea)
                {
                    g.setColor(Color.MAGENTA);
                }
                int rx = x * size;
                int ry = y * size;
                g.fillRect(rx, ry, size, size);
                g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                g.drawString(x+","+y, rx, ry);
                g.drawRect(rx, ry, size, size);
            }
        }

        //g.setStroke(new BasicStroke(1.0f/size));
        AffineTransform at = g.getTransform();
        g.scale(size, size);
        g.setColor(new Color(0,255,0,128));
        g.draw(p);
        g.setTransform(at);

    }
}
```

If you only want to handle pixels in rectangles, there might be a "manual" solution for what you want to achieve.